# Ubuntu Touch Desktop Mode on Nexus 10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, external-monitor, nexus-10

does the current available version of Ubuntu Touch for Nexus 10 support the Desktop Mode (showing the full Desktop on an external Monitor)?
If yes, how can I activate it? Plug in HDMI Montior and USB Keyboard? Does it have to be triggered separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not implemented right now, will propably be included in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Release.

Comment: Any updates on this?